# Geometry nodes - How to select the largest duplicate index of each mesh islands

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have 2 faces as mesh islands, each has random duplicate amount so how do I select the largest dup index of each mesh island?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with this setting:

[image]

Which outputs:

[image]

- Capture the original face indices
- Accumulate "one" for each original face index (with group ID from the captured index), as accumulation is done following the index order
- Compare the leading (last) to the total: this comparison indicates the last duplicated element

For each group ID (so for each original face), you'll have:

leading: 1, 2, ... n

and total: n, n, ... n

So the last is when leading = total.

[image]

---

Alternative approach (more simple):

[image]

- Capture the amount of duplicates for each face
- Compare the duplicate index (+ 1) to this amount

Comment: Perfect! This is just what I needed, thanks mate.

Answer (score 5):

There is an even simpler solution in this specific case - **the duplicate faces are offset above the originals**.

It uses the **Raycast** Node with minimum additional nodes and is executed after the **Set Position** Node:

[image]

The principle is as follows: Use the faces as source positions of the rays and slightly offset them so you don't get self hit. Use the Z+ Ray Direction vector (0,0,1). Each ray will hit the face above it. Invert the **Is Hit** output result to select the faces that do not have anything above them.

The **lemon's** solution is superior as it doesn't depend on the vertical offset of the faces.